# How to overload operator += in cpp?

Tags: c++

I have some problem with overloading += operator

I want to add a item to vector (getAuthorList) with += operator

How can I do it in main ?

Code snippet (header file) :

```
class Author {  

public:
    Author(std::string firstName, std::string lastname, std::string affiliation);

    std::string getFirstName();
    std::string getLastName();
    std::string getAffiliation();

    void setFirstName(std::string);
    void setLastName(std::string);
    void setAffiliation(std::string);

    void printFullName();

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Author& author);

private:
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastname;
    std::string affiliation;

};


class Publication {
public :

    Publication(std::string tiltle, Date publishDate, std::string publisher);

    vector<Author> getAuthorList();

    Author& operator+=(Author);

private:
    vector<Author> authorList;
};
```

Comment: [Your code compiles](https://wandbox.org/permlink/svJPSXklmgUgKUfK) with some headers added. What is your problem?

Comment: `Author &operator+=(Author)` as a member of `Publication` is unusual.   At best, it is not idiomatic C++,  at worst it will confuse programmers attempting to use your classes. When doing `a += b`, the returned result is typically (a reference to) `a` but your `operator+=()` cannot return `a` since it returns a different type. When doing `some_publication += some_author` it will make more sense to the vast majority of C++ programmers if the result is a `Publication &`, not an `Author &`.   (The fact it is technically possible to do what you have , does not mean it is good technique).

Comment: I might be completely wrong here, but to my knowledge, `+=` is just an abbreviation of `+`, like `a+=1` is the same as `a=a+1`, so if you want to overload `+=`, you might need to overload `+` instead, and the overload of `+=` will be a simple consequence of this. Can anybody tell me if I'm right or wrong here?

Comment: @Dominique - In C++ - and in the context of this question in particular - you are flat out wrong.   For basic numeric types, yes,  `a += b` is (more or less) a shorthand for `a = (a + b)`, just like it is in C.   For class types or other user-defined types, supplying an `operator+()` does not implicitly also provide a corresponding `operator+=()` or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overload `+=` operator like this

```
void operator+=(Author);
```

Change the operator return type to void as you are storing it in Publication class so it does not make any sense to return The same author from this operator.
you can write the operator definition like this

```
void Publication::operator+=(Author auth){
    this->authorList.push_back(auth);
}
```

here is the working example:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
class Author {  
public:
    Author(const std::string& name):
        Name(name){

        }
    const std::string& getName() const{
        return Name;
    }
private:
    std::string Name;
};

class Publication {
public :

    Publication(){

    }
    void operator+=(Author);
    void getAuthorList(){
        for (const auto& author: authorList){
            std::cout << author.getName() << std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<Author> authorList;
};

void Publication::operator+=(Author auth){
    this->authorList.push_back(auth);
}

int main(){
    Publication pub;
    Author auth("Alice");
    pub += auth;
    Author auth2("Mark");
    pub += auth2;
    pub.getAuthorList();
}
```

Note: I just tried to make simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `std::vector` method called `push_back` inside the implementation block of your overloaded operator.